# flutter calling bottom sheet and popup from bottom sheet and refresh first screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I used the bottom sheet and I'm using navigator.pop on the button inside the bottom sheet but want to refresh the first screen when calling popup...

**code**

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext bc) {
      return Container(
        child: Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
          
          ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.delete),
              title: Text('delete'),
              onTap: () async {
                

                try {
                  final file = await File(path);
                  print(path);
                  await file.delete();


                  print(file);
                } catch (e) {
                  print(e.toString());

                }
                Navigator.pop(context);
                setState(() {
                  print('delete');
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This perfectly work's for me and hoping that also work's for you.`

Note:- If you note get data then call that method many times.

If You try to get data from any method then call that method after `

```
Navigator.pop(context)
method name();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String homeScreenText = "Bottom Sheet not opened";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text(homeScreenText),
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showBS();
              },
              child: const Text("open bottom sheet"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  showBS() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return SizedBox(
          height: 300,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                // Delete item from the list
                  // then call these
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: const Text("Close")),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i used bottom sheet as a function and then call that funtion in ontap and setstate not working inside function

Comment: show Try importing the library that defines 'setState', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'setState'

Comment: you need to use statefull widget for use setState(());

Comment: fine i used delet function inside bottom sheet but when navigator.pop it shows the file but when refresh that screen then it delet i want to refresh the screenoutside bottom sheet when we popup bottom sheet

Comment: i coudnt understand you. Can you add some code on this question

Comment: i have a bottom sheet inside bottom sheet i have a button and that button delet files from list now i want to move back from bottom sheet once the delet button tap.With navigator.pop it moves back to the screen i want but i want to refresh that screen to not show the delet file

Comment: i have a screen before bottom sheet which contain list and in trailing which contain icon to open bottom sheet

Comment: delet file inside bottom sheet want to move back but refresh the screen which contain list of files

Comment: pls check above code. Remove item from the list inside bottom sheet's button click then call the setState and pop.

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: pls show your code

Comment: code shareddddd

Answer (score -1):

You just need to pass class name beside the Navigator.

Like this:-

```
Navigator.pop(context,classname());
```

Comment: tried but not refreshing that class

Comment: want to go back and refresh the screen which im in

Comment: can you pls what kind of data are you want to refresh...(I'm facing the same problem 3 days ago)

Comment: list of files after getting from device storage